# How to escape asterisk in regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex, escaping

I want to use the pattern `*1*`. I have tried `\*1\*`, but it doesn't work. Where is the problem?

Comment: @Mike Don't know if you'll see this, but thanks for switching the slashes. It got ninja-edited either while I was editing or while it was in the review queue.

Comment: @jdwire yeah I saw it. The other edits looked good, so I just reverted that one part.

Comment: @ohTHATaaronbrown : tags

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You have to escape it with a backslash:

```
/\*1\*/
```

Otherwise, an unescaped `*` in a RegExp will mean: Match 0 or more of the Preceding Character Group.

Update:

If you use the `RegExp` constructor, do it this way:

```
new RegExp("\\*1\\*")
```

You have to double-escape the backslashes because they need to be escaped in the string itself.

Comment: i have edited my question, but yes i used backslash and it doesn't work

Comment: The forward slashes mark the start and the end of the regexp. You have to start with a forward slash and end with one, and in between escape the asterisks with backslashes. Exactly like in the example I've given.

Comment: no but i m using RegExp constructor so i don't need to use forward slash

Comment: @user2080105 I updated my question. If you construct a RegExp via a string, you'll have to double-escape. If you're using some other tool, please document it in your question.

Comment: @BeatRichartz you mean you updated your answer?

Answer (score 0):

need to use a backslash `\` as the escape character in regexes.

Comment: i have edited my question, but yes i used backslash and it doesn't work